# laravel 4: always the fourth controller method doesn't work->blank page

Tags: php, laravel-4

All the first three methods of all my controller work well, but when i add a fourth one this one doesn't work (the construct method not included) and give me a blank page with the url of the controller action.
my controller class:

```
class StoreController extends BaseController{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->beforeFilter('csrf', ['on'=>'post']);
    }

    public function getIndex(){
        return View::make('store.index', ['products'=>Product::take(4)->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get()]);
    }

    public function getView($id){
        return View::make('store.view', ['product'=>Product::find($id)]);
    }

    public function getCategory($cat_id){
        return View::make('store.category', [
            'products'=>Product::where('category_id','=',$cat_id)->paginate(6),
            'category'=>Category::find($cat_id)]);
    }

    public function getSearch(){
        $keyword=Input::get('keyword');
        return View::make('store.search', [
            'products'=>Product::where('title','LIKE','%'.$keyword.'%')->get(),
            'keyword'=>$keyword]);
    }

}
```

In my route.php file:

```
Route::controller('store', 'Storecontroller');
```

And the triggerer form of the action is:

```
<div id="search-form">
                    {{ Form::open(['url'=>'store/search', 'method'=>'get']) }}
                        {{ Form::text('keyword', null, ['placeholder'=>'Search by keyword', 'class'=>'search']) }}
                        {{ Form::submit('Search', ['class'=>'search submit']) }}
                    {{ Form::close() }}
```

as I said the getSearch method doesn't work and I'm given a blank page with the url of the action (not the returned view)
thanks

Comment: It looks like the `Input::get()` part is causing the issue. Add a default to it like e.g. `Input::get('keyword', 'default')` and try again. You could also implement a check if the keyword is set with e.g. `if (Input::has('keyword')) {...} else {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

**As the page is blank**, make sure that [debug](http://laravel.com/docs/errors#configuration) is set to `true` in your app config (should be the topmost setting, preferably in the [local dir](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration)). This means that when an error occurs you will be shown an error page with a detailed stack trace and error message, making it easier for you to debug your app.

**Make sure that** the view `store.search` exists, is named correctly (check for typos) and contains the html/php you need to display the `$products`.

Next, you have two possibilities:

1. Set a default value for the `keyword` input

   ```
   // For example:

   Input::get('keyword', 'default')
   ```
2. Check if there is a keyword specified

   ```
   // For example:

   if (Input::has('keyword')) {...} else {...}
   ```

***As a side note:*** You should not perform (heavy) tasks inside of arrays like you do here. Put them inside variables and include them into the view array like you did with the keyword variable. Your code will also be more readable and maintainable. There's a lot more about this, but thats of the point here.

Let me know if this helped you.

Comment: for the debug: it is already set to true and shecked for the input:get as yo said Ithink is the problem is that the action is not executed because I simply wrote 'return "hello"' inside the method and I still had blank page.

Comment: Also when I execute php artisan routes (MS DOS) the controller methode is listed in the black screen

Comment: @AmineC Did you change anything yet? Like adding the default input value?

Comment: There seems to be a typo in your route `Route::controller('store', 'Storecontroller');`. _Store**C**ontroller_ instead of Store**c**ontroller. Next, remove `parent::__construct();` from your controller `__construct()`. Then, with eloquent use `firstOrFail()` instead of `get()` and put that line into a `try {...} catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {...}`. [This will throw an exception if the model is not found.](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage) Remember to change it into ->get() after debugging as this only returns one result. Give it a try and tell me if this works.